# Grep and regex diffrent behavior on shell script won't work properly

Tags: regex, grep, sh

I'm currently working on a shell script and i've to check if a string A in contained in string B.

So i immediately wrote out (with "key" as example)

```
if [ `echo "$KEY" | grep "\$"` ]
```

However for some reason, on my shell script the output of

```
echo "$KEY" | grep "\$"
```

returns "value"

After testing the same command on zshrc i got a different result (nothing as expected)

Anyone knows where it might come from ?

Edit : After reworking how i wrote out my script, i changed the "" quotes to '' and got a correct result for

```
echo "$KEY" | grep '\$'
```

However my test is still getting through writing out

```
[ if `echo "$KEY" | grep '\$'` ]
```

Comment: If you want `echo` to print a literal string `$KEY` you need to put it in single quotes, not double. Apparently in your first experiment you had defined an environment variable `KEY` containing the string `value`.

Comment: And `grep '$'` matches all inputs. If you want to `grep` for a literal dollar sign, `grep -F '$'` or `grep '\$'` (or equivalently `grep "\\$"`) or `grep '[$]'` does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more idiomatic and straightforward way is to use the shell's `case` statement. The syntax is slightly eerie and there are still some metacharacters to cope with, but not the full regex set like with `grep`.

```
case '$key' in
  *\$* ) echo contained ;;
  * ) echo not ;;
esac
```